# htaccess breaking css,js, image path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two static pages inside `directory` and trying to rewrite `URL` to access them fro the root. It is my `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^mypage$ dir_1/mypage.html
RewriteRule ^myotherpage$ dir_2/myotherpage.html
```

When I write `www.mydomain.com/mypage` it goes on the right page, but all `.css`, `.js` etc.. does not have good path anymore. They all refer to `/` and not anymore to `/dir_1` or `/dir_2`.

How can I solve this? I tried with some `RewriteCond` but did not for me. 
I don't want to use an absolute `path` due to several reasons.

Comment: I don't see why people insist on using relative links especially when using mod_rewrite for friendly URL's. It saves so many problems using absolute paths. I host my CSS and JS one a personal CDN so I must use a absolute path anyway and it always works. Even SO uses CDN for static content.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use absolute paths then you can try adding this in your page's HTML header:

```
<base href="/" />
```